# Why do I have this right white space on my website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently learning web design, and I have made a little Site for a friend of mine.
I have a white box on the right side along the whole screen, which pushes my contend to the left. Seems like a padding, or a margin, or something. But I can't find the Problem?

Its in the responsive view also!
Image of responsive view:
[image: Image of responsive view]
The Site is online at https://tastenwichser24.de/.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, you would need to post here the code for us to check the problem. You don't have to upload the entire site code, just a sample that demonstrates the problem. You can use codepen for it: https://codepen.io/

Comment: Ah oh okay! Is it not enough to read the source code on the website?

Comment: It would be too time consuming and not effective.

Comment: @BenjaminFranz - You might want to read [mcve] ... it explains what's needed and how it should be done.

Comment: Thank you for the article about minimal reproducible example, its very helpful!

Comment: hey Benjamin, get used to using developer tools. download firefox or chrome and use the inspect option. this is going ot be a big help for you. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are doing sliding animations and it overflowed. In line 178 `<section>` tag try adding a `overflow-x:hidden`.

Comment: 0

Oh man thank you! Still having troubles to bring my code on codepen, to many css files and to few structure in my code :P

I wonder about this because the problem came from an animated element that slides in from the left! But the overflow was right. How can that be?